# No launcher activity found while loading Application

Tags: android, android-launcher

This is what my `AndroinManifest.xml` looks like

```
<manifest package="com.dz122596.bubblebop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"    <!-- THIS ICON(IMAGE) WILL BE SHOWN IN YOUR APPS -->
    android:label="@string/app_name"     <!-- HERE LABEL(APP NAME) -->
    <activity
        android:name=".startingpoint"  <!-- (.)dot means current dir, if your activity is in another package then give cull package name ex: com.xxx.Activity  -->
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

And startingpoint.java the activity Iam trying to launch is in the same package but when I run it says no launcher activity found.

Comment: Can you upload the first line of your startingpoint class ? I means that `package  ...` line

Comment: Show ur Package name.. Also clean your project. Uninstall app from device and relaunch again.

Comment: Please close your <application … > start tag in manifest.

Comment: <manifest package="com.dz122596.bubblebop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Comment: i cant find the app on the emulator? sorry ime total noob

Comment: Do one thing. Post your full **AndroidManifest.xml** file with proper format.

Comment: @user3339768 Please open your stratingpoint activity file and tell me its first line.

Comment: made some changes to code closed <application> but still not working

Comment: @kedarnath package com.dz122596.bubblebop;

Comment: here is a screenshot of everything http://grab.by/uyZi

Comment: @user3339768: just put this com.dz122596.bubblebop.startingpoint Actvity tag inside <Application> tag

Comment: @kevz http://grab.by/uyZq did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest file's code says that your forgot to end the `Application` tag. You need to write `</application>` before `</manifest>` tag. Just add it and your problem will be solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.dz122596.bubblebop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"    
    android:label="@string/app_name" >    
    <activity
        android:name=".startingpoint"  
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>                <!-- Add this closing tag -->
</manifest>
```

Comment: @user3339768 why you put `>` after this line `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` , Just copy & paste code from my answer and see it will work.

Comment: @user3339768 , Now please try aagain by copy & paste my answer into your manifest.xml file

Comment: sorry its still doing the same thing it shows error then when i do ctrl+shft+f to format correctly error goes away but it still dont work

Comment: @user3339768 I got it, there was one more missing `>` I edited my answer, please try again.

Comment: thank you for helping i accidently deleted my startingpoint.java file so ill start all over and try to fix things with your suggestions

Comment: I have updated my answer, there was missing of first line. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

just make few changes to ur manifest file. follow below manifewst file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name="com.dz122596.bubblebop.startingpoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```